# OpenGL does not read the colour correctly from my vertex array

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

With OpenGL shaders, I want to draw a triangle on the screen, where the vertex colours are specified in the data structure alongside the vertex coordinates. The structure has 7 floats for each vertex -- 3 for coordinates, followed by 4 for colour:

```
static std::vector<GLfloat> vertices = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };
```

I then tell OpenGL how to interpret this structure by using glVertexAttribPointer():

```
// Vertex coordinates
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(float), 0);
// Vertex colour
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
```

And then tell my vertex shader to read the coordinates and colour:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 vertex_colour;
```

However, no matter what values I use for the colour component, the triangle is always drawn in red. Changing the coordinates in the structure affects the image as expected, but changing the colour in the structure does nothing.

I believe that this is a problem with my C++ code, rather than the shader code, because I have debugged the shader and it is always reading (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) for the colour, even though I am passing it (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) for each vertex.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/ext.hpp>

GLuint buffer;
GLuint projection_matrix_location;
GLuint view_matrix_location;
glm::mat4 view_matrix;
glm::mat4 projection_matrix;
int num_vertices = 0;

static void RenderScene()
{
    // Clear the buffers.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the matrices
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection_matrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view_matrix));

    // Specify how to read the vertex buffer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    // Vertex coordinates
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(float), 0);
    // Vertex colour
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));

    // Draw the vertex buffer
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, num_vertices);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Swap the buffers
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void MakeBuffers()
{
    // Set the vertices
    static std::vector<GLfloat> vertices = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };
    num_vertices = (1.0 / 7.0) * vertices.size();

    // Fill the buffer with the vertices
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, num_vertices * 7 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}


static GLuint MakeShader(GLenum shader_type, std::string shader_filename)
{
    // Load the source code
    std::ifstream file_in;
    file_in.open(&shader_filename[0]);
    std::stringstream file_stream;
    file_stream << file_in.rdbuf();
    std::string file_string = file_stream.str();
    const GLchar* ptr_file_string = &file_string[0];
    const GLchar** ptr_file_strings = &ptr_file_string;
    int string_lengths[] = {(int)file_string.length()};

    // Compile the shader
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shader_type);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, ptr_file_strings, &string_lengths[0]);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    // Check
    GLint is_success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &is_success);
    if (!is_success)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return shader;
}


static void MakeShaderProgram()
{
    // Make the shaders
    GLuint vertex_shader = MakeShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "../src/vertex-shader.glsl");
    GLuint fragment_shader = MakeShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "../src/fragment-shader.glsl");

    // Create the program
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    // Check
    GLint is_success = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &is_success);
    if (!is_success)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    glValidateProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &is_success);
    if (!is_success)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Use the program
    glUseProgram(program);

    // Get the location of the uniform variables
    view_matrix_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "view_matrix");
    assert(view_matrix_location != 0xFFFFFFFF);
    projection_matrix_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection_matrix");
    assert(projection_matrix_location != 0xFFFFFFFF);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    // Configure some GLUT display options:
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    // Specify the GLUT window parameters and create the window
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 750);
    glutInitWindowPosition(500, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");

    // Specify the display callback
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

    // Initialize GLEW, which must be done after GLUT is initialized.
    GLenum glut_result = glewInit();
    if (glut_result != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the clear colour.
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth testing so that only the nearest vertex is sent to the colour buffer (also needed to read the depth of each pixel using glReadPixels())).
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Make the vertex and index buffers.
    MakeBuffers();

    // Make the shader program.
    MakeShaderProgram();

    // Create the view matrix.
    glm::vec3 eye(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
    glm::vec3 centre(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    view_matrix = glm::lookAt(eye, centre, up);

    // Create the projection matrix.
    float fov_y = 45.0;
    float aspect_ratio = 1.5;
    float near_clip = 1;
    float far_clip = 1000;
    projection_matrix = glm::perspective(fov_y, aspect_ratio, near_clip, far_clip);

    // Start the GLUT internal loop.
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

And here is my shader code:

```
// Vertex shader

#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 vertex_colour;

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;

out vec4 frag_colour;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    frag_colour = vertex_colour;
}


// Fragment shader

#version 330

in vec4 frag_colour;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = frag_colour;
}
```

Comment: if you already decided to use modern OpenGL then use cusom frag shader output  like: out vec4 COLOR_OUT;COLOR_OUT = frag_colour;

Comment: Also,in your draw method you are not enabling second array which should be the colors/

Comment: I suspect there is an issue with color format somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't debug your code now,but based on what I see here you forgot to enable second attribute array.See [this example](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=4483.0) for reference.
But even if I am wrong,I would like to point you to some bad practices you have in your code.You are using GL 3.3 which is good.This is modern OpenGL baseline.But you are still mixing old API (pre 3.3) with the new one.From the end:

In your fragment shader you should use custom output attribute rather than the GLSL built in gl_FragColor.

```
 #version 330

 in smooth vec4 frag_colour;
 out vec4 frag_out;

 void main()
 {
    frag_out = frag_colour;
 }
```

Now,regarding your OpenGL commands.You shouldn't bind vertex buffers directly but use [VAO](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt)  and bind it to the context.In fact some driver version (I experienced on NVIDIA) produce no rendering results at all when VAO is not used with core profile.